# url rewrite using htaccess mandating to give absolute path of css

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a main php file and in which i am doing all the stuff related to my website.

I have edited .htaccess file as follow to rewrite the URL

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule /(.*)-(.*)/$ index.php?uds=$1&vid=$2
```

I have created separate file for JS & CSS (PHP only) and for footer JS (PHP). Now, I'm including this JS and CSS PHP files in my index.php file.

But the problem is in the footer.php and header.php files, I have to give
../../css/bootstraph.css path.

Is there a solution by which I don't have to update this header and footer.php files?

Comment: It's not very clear to me what your problem is, exactly. Providing your directory structure with some example code pointing out the real problem might help. I suspect you are having problems with the php include path, but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information in your post, but if the problem is in providing correct pathes to different scripts/styles after URL has been rewrited - then I suggest to simply use:

```
<base href="http://www.your-website.com/">
```

in the document's HEAD section. So, it would be no matter if you load the page, for example, your-site.com/page1 or your-site.com/section1/subsection/page12345 - all pathes to scripts/styles would be equal.

Comment: I have added that tag.. but still not working.. not able to understand where the problem is

Comment: If you correctly set all your pathes from the root of website - it must work, I insert this tag in HTML in many of my projects where URL Rewriting is used. For real example (open the source code): http://raroom.com/chairs/chairs_metallic -> we are not opening the main page (because of "chairs/metallic", but pathes like <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css"> loads perfectly (no "../../" at all). Maybe, the problem is in your styles? Are you sure, your CSS files don't have broken pathes in them?